# formate date in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var mydate = new Date();
var theyear = mydate.getFullYear();
var themonth = mydate.getMonth() + 1;
var thetoday = mydate.getDate();

txtbox.value="04-Jul-2012"
```

I have to convert todays date and txtbox date in "04/07/2012" format  how i do it.

I have to compare todays date with txtbox date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use date.js javascript library.
http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/

```
var d1 = Date.parse('04-Jul-2012');
alert(d1.toString('dd/MM/yyyy'));
```

Date comparison

```
var today = Date.today();
var past = Date.today().add(-6).days();
var future = Date.today().add(6).days();


Date.compare(today, future);                    // -1
Date.compare(today, new Date().clearTime());    // 0
Date.compare(today, past)                       // 1
```